# How to format a parameter set in a Kendo UI External Template for a ListView?

Tags: jquery, listview, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI External Template that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="dispositivosTemplate">
    <div class="containerElement" style="background-color: transparent" value="${UniqueId}" onclick="showSubsettingDetails(this)">
        <dl>
            <dd class="elementList dispositivoElement">${UniqueId}: ${Ubicacion}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <br/>
</script>
```

I set this template with the following code:

```
var template = '#dispositivosTemplate';
var dataSourceList = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: src
});
$('#listView').kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSourceList,
    template: kendo.template($(template).html())
});
```

where *src* is an array of objects obtained through an AJAX call, every object has an *Ubicacion* property of string type, which value tends to be quite long.

What I want to do is to give format to the way the property *Ubicacion* is being displayed in my Kendo UI ListView, for example, instead of having the following displayed in a item in the ListView *"Calle Santa Lucia, State of Mexico, Mexico"*, change it so it looks like this *"Called Santa Lucia..."* without changing the original value in the *Ubicacion* property.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of javascript code in template definition is explained here:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/templates/expressions.html

However if all you want to do is make displayed text shorter, then you might want to check out `text-overflow: ellipsis` css property

edit: and even better tutorial is here:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview

Comment: I would like to avoid mixing Javascript in my templates, doesn't seem a good practice to follow. As for the `text-overflow` property it doesn't seem to do anything in the dd tag. Does it apply on DIVs only?

Comment: In addition to `text-overflow: ellipsis` define `overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap`. Then it should work also for `<dd>`